# DSS File not convert using FFMPEG

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, audio-converter

I am trying to convert the dss audio file into wav format but it gives me error "Invalid data found when processing input" while converting.

i use below command line :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Source filepath" "destination filepath"
```

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Check with a recent build (< 3 days old)

Comment: same problem with latest version also

Comment: Use latest nightly binary, not release version. Release versions are not up to date.

Comment: can you please give me syntax for this because no idea about nightly binary

Comment: Same syntax. Get binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: hi, now above problem solved and file creates perfact as original but in convert file it audio play not well after some minutes.

Comment: Tried ffmpeg with dss just now and it worked great. ffmpeg version 6.0